# Azure Stream Analytics partition key column duplicated in table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I have an Azure Stream Analytics query coming straight from Event Hubs and going into Table Storage. Query is:

```
SELECT *
INTO [TableOutput]
FROM [InputEvents]
```

The input body has an Id Guid and a CreatedAt date-time. These are used as the Partition Key and Row Key for the table output respectively.

Although, the columns Id and CreatedAt also appear in the table. How can I use these columns for partition and row keys, but not have them appear in the columns in the output table?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported today - the columns you choose as partition key and row key will still be outputted as data columns.

Comment: Two years later still the same?